# How to access Normal and Tangential force values of objects during physics simulation?

Tags: python, scripting, physics, rigid-body-simulation, soft-body

I have a couple of soft body objects that collide with each other as shown below. My goal is to get information on the Normal and Tangential forces for the selected shape. I wonder, is it possible to access such information in Blender for the vertices/faces of each object for each frame, ideally through the Python API?

Based on what I see during the physics simulation (maybe not very obvious in this video) it is clear to me that the Bullet physics engine is able to calculate Normal and Tangential forces to simulate friction. So even if the Python API does not provide such information directly, I assume there should be a hacky way to access to such forces using Blender's source code. Any advice on this would be greatly helpful as well.

[image]